# How to avoid 0 forecasts for a time series with decreasing trend?

Tags: r, parameters, forecasting, holtwinters

I am trying to apply the holt-winter method to multiple time series with 36 data points and trying to predict for 16 future time periods in R. There are some time series with a decreasing trend for which I am getting negative numbers as forecast values. How can I avoid generating negative numbers as forecast?

I have already tried generating forecast with damped = T, but still negative numbers are generated as forecasts.

```
fit_ets1 <- ets(y = sales_ts1, model = "ZZZ")
fit_ets_forecast1 <- forecast(fit_ets1, h = holdoutPeriod)
```

Comment: `fit_ets_forecast1[fit_ets_forecast1 < 0] <- 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
fit_ets1 <- ets(y = sales_ts1, model = "ZZZ", lambda=0)
fit_ets_forecast1 <- forecast(fit_ets1, h = holdoutPeriod, biasadj=TRUE)
```

This will create forecasts on the log scale, so the back-transformed forecasts will be positive. See https://otexts.com/fpp2/limits.html.